# How to read json folder data using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to get the data of json folders using Python 3.7.2.

This is my json file:

```
{"device": 
  [
    {"name": "device1", "status": 0},
    {"name": "device2", "status": 1},
    {"name": "device2", "status": 1}
  ]
}
```

For my project I need following variables:

- variable of all devices gathered in a list:

  ```
   devices = ["device1", "device1", "device1"]
  ```
- status of devices saved in different variables:

  ```
   status_device1 = 0
   status_device2 = 1
   status_device3 = 1
  ```

*It is possible to change the structure of the json file, but it has to be only one json file, so I need something like:*

```
jdevices = getDevices(json_data)             | Output: {'device1', 'device2', 'device3'}
```

*and:*

```
jstatus = getStatus(json_data, "device1")    | Output: 0
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: You should not want _Variable names_ that are read from data, like JSON. If your code will only deal with these 3 devieces, and you know it in advance, that is ok. Otherwise, you should have  a dictionary with the status devices and a key for each device in this dictionary.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? I agree with @jsbueno, this sounds a bit like a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

class DeviceHelper:

    def __init__(self, json_file):
        """open json file and load json content"""
        with open(json_file, 'rb') as file:
            self.device_info = json.load(file)

    def get_device_status(self, name):
        """loop over the divices list and compare"""
        for device in self.device_info.get('device'):
            if device.get('name') == name:
                return device.get('status')
        return 'Lol no device found'

    def get_devices(self):
        return [device.get('name') for device in self.device_info.get('device')]

# path to json file
device_info = DeviceHelper('devices.json')

device_info.get_device_status('device2')
>>> 1
device_info.get_devices()
>>> ['device1', 'device2', 'device2']
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but your solution only works fot device1...
Is there a way to rewrite the code?

Answer (score 1):

python has built-in support for JSON files, and it also has a very handy data structure named [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) which works brilliantly with JSON.

You'll basically need to do this:

- tell python how to interact with JSON files: `import json`
- load your data: `data = jason.loads("path_to_file")`
- do whatever you'd want with the data, e.g. iterate over it:

`for x in data:
    print(f"x: {x},  data[x]: {data[x]}")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
jsn = {"device": [
    {"name": "device1", "status": 0},
    {"name": "device2", "status": 1},
    {"name": "device2", "status": 1}]}

df = pd.DataFrame(jsn['device'])
```

```
      name  status
0  device1       0
1  device2       1
2  device2       1
```

```
devices = df['name'].tolist()
status = df['status'].tolist()
```